# How do I create a counter in excel for groups?

Tags: excel, grouping, counter

I am really befuddled as to how I create a counter that increments by 1 every time it finds Type=A (there are only two Types:  A and B).  I want to use this later as a grouping variable so I can sum the duration of each of the events.

My spreadsheet only has columns A, B, and C and I need a formula for Column D (Event)

```
A                   B            C                 D
DateTime            Type      Duration          Event
23Nov1973  0700      A                            1
24Nov1973  0700      A            1               1
25Nov1973  0700      A            1               1
25Nov1973  1800      B  
26Nov1973  0700      B  
26Nov1973  1300      A            0.25            2
26Nov1973  1800      B  
27Nov1973  0700      B  
27Nov1973  1300      B  
27Nov1973  1800      A            0.208           3
28Nov1973  0700      A            0.541           3
28Nov1973  1300      A            0.25            3
28Nov1973  1800      B            
29Nov1973  0700      A            0.541           4
29Nov1973  1300      A            0.25            4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Type` data starts from `B2` cell, then:

1. write in `D2` formula: `=IF(B2="B","",1)`
2. write in `D3` following formula: `=IF(B3="B","",IF(D2="",MAX($D$2:D2)+1,D2))`
   and drag it down